# which database should I use?

Tags: android, database, push-notification, server, web-farm

I am planning to build a web application and android app, which will manage huge numbers of notification (push notification), and can work in slow internet connection too. I need to send and get instant notifications. Number of users can be thousands or millions, application will have multiple servers (web farm), multiple database. Now I need to decide that which database will be best for this kind of application and which language should I use for programming. Please help me out. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I Blindly Suggest you to Use Parse Cloud Database,as it provides SDK for All mobile Environments like Android and IOS for easy implementation and also it recently Launched a Javascript SDK to use.Its free for Trial.MultiPlatform Support and Secure

Check it out Here: https://www.parse.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to decide what your immediate needs are. Are you going to use this on a platforms that could potentially have hundreds of people accessing information at the same time? Then you need to estimate your future needs.

This will help you to decide your database system.

As per my experience i am suggesting you to use MYSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you going to get to thousands and millions users ? Everyone starts from scratch (read: zero users, except some friends). By this I mean, that you have to concentrate on what's the real issue within your development (growing app user base is different story):

1. Creation of Android app and it's lifecycle (updates, support of previous versions & etc).
2. Back-end. Will I also work on Back-end. Working on 2 'projects' (Android app and it's back-end) isn't easy. Not everyone is experienced enough to work on multiple assignments at the same time.
3. Valuate an option of using SaaS/Paas backend. Most of the have trial or free version for developer.

Third option is great. Get cheap/free web host. Store there configuration, that your Android app will download when it starts. In configuration you should declare what's the back-end and how to communicate with it. You can use any of known services like https://www.firebase.com or https://parse.com/plans or even use Google App engine free tier / AWS free tier.

About developing app for Android - if your app doesn't need any complex calculation or libraries - just write it with JavaScript. It's fast enough. Though, Java apps are always faster and easier to debug.

Good luck !